# Get info from Woocommerce checkout to Javascript function (JSon data)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to get the values of Billing Address in Wordpress Woocommerce checkout (Name, last name, etc) AND the chart data (product description, id, total, etc) and use them in Javascript function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need jQuery and for get values of input fields in json-format :

```
var values = JSON.stringify($('form[name="checkout"]').serializeArray());
console.log(values);
```

For productinformations & total you need to look at html objects content and put in a array and do like above "JSON.stringify".

The objects can variate on different themes